# Confusion with how createStore works in redux

Tags: redux

I was learning Redux and came across createStore function. So, as I understood createStore receives 3 parameters:

```
reducer
initial state
enhancers (for simplicity we will use only middlewares)
```

But when we use createStore in action we do not pass initial state as the second argument BUT pass reducer with default state like this:

```
const initialState = {counter:0}
const reducer =(state=initialState, action)=>...
```

The question is why don't we put the initial state as the second argument but pass initialState to reducer?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the `initial` state of **a reducer** to that of the global state of your app.

Global state simply means that combined state of all the reducers in your app.

For simplicity let's just assume you only have one reducer in your app.

#### Reducer :

```
function todos(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return state.concat([action.text])
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

So this simple function `todos` is our reducer which will give us the current state tree, whenever it is run.

So this is our first parameter to `createStore`.

#### Initial State :

```
['Understanding Store']
```

Let's assume our initial state as an array which contains 1 item as shown above.

This will be our second parameter to `createStore`.

Now we create our store like this:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'

//... code
.
.
.
const store = createStore(todos, ['Understanding Store'])
```

Now our store is created. 
Nothing fancy, store is basically an object, which has few methods on it.

One of those methods is `dispatch`. 
This method helps in `dispatching` an action, which will run through our reducer and then update the state.

So when we do this

```
store.dispatch({
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  text: 'Learn methods on Store'
})
```

This will update our state as below:

```
['Understanding Store','Learn methods on Store']
```

But when your app grows big, you might want to create different functions (reducers) to manage different parts of your global state.

If we have one more reducer, say `counter.js` :

```
export default function counter(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state + 1
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state - 1
    default:
      return state
  }
```

}

Then to combine our 1st reducer todos and this counter reducer, we have an utility called `combineReducer`.

#### rootReducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import todos from './todos'
import counter from './counter'

export default combineReducers({
  todos,
  counter
})
```

Then using `createStore`, you just do this:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './rootReducer.js;

const store = createStore(rootReducer);
```

There are certain rules that you need to follow while using `combineReducers`.

Read the rules [here](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers#notes)

Answer (score 0):

The use case for passing an initial state as the second argument in `createStore` is intended for use cases where you get this initial state from the outside when loading your app. Examples could be state generated on the server for server-side rendered applications that are hydrated on the client, or an application that restores the redux state form local-storage when loaded.

The initial value of a single reducer should be returned when the reducer function is called with undefined state, the easiest way is to use a default argument for state:

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => ...
```

This allows you to define the `initialState` close to where the reducer is defined and it scales nicely with `combineReducers` when you have a larger number of reducers. If you would put all the initialState of all reducers into one object that is passed to `createStore` this would become difficult to keep in sync.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have actually confused createStore with a reducer. Think of createStore as a function which returns you a collection of reducers by adding in a certain middleWares and other functionalities like dispatch

More often than not you have multiple reducers in your app and you actually combine them using `combineReducers`

Say for example you combineReducers is

```
import userReducer from 'reducers/user';
import authReducer from 'reducers/auth';
import countReducer from 'reducers/count';
const reducers = combineReducers({
   userReducer,
   authReducer,
   countReducer,
});
```

Now the initialState to createStore must be of the format of an object with keys as `userReducer, authReducer, countReducer` and then the individual reducers state. For example

```
{
   userReducer: { id: 1, name: 'Test'},
   authReducer: { isLoading: true, isAuthenticated: false},
   countReducer: {counter: 0}
}
```

Now thing of the second keys as equivalent to initialState each individual reducer

For example: reducer/count.js

```
const initialState = {counter:0}
const reducer =(state=initialState, action)=>...
```

The way it works is that createStore would actually call the reducer with the action each time action is invoked like

```
reducer(state, action);
```

In case of combineReducer it works like below

```
const combineReducers = (reducers) => {
    return (state, action) => {
        const tempState = { ...state };
        Object.keys(reducers).forEach((key) => {
            tempState[key] = reducers[key](tempState[key], action);
        });
        return tempState;
    };
};
```

and for the initial time it invokes it with

```
reducer(initialState, {type: "@@redux/INIT"});
```

so that each reducer's initial state is populated

`P.S.` If you do not pass the initialState to createStore, each reducer takes in the default argument passed to to it like `const reducer =(state=initialState, action)=>` and returns state for default switch clause causing the initialState from each reducer to be used